# HTML5 FileReader failing to trigger functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the HTML5 FileReader to load a CSV file, but its `onLoad` function never triggers (tried with Firefox and Chrome). This is despite its `result` property being populated with the file's contents, its `readyState` being set to 2 (DONE), and its `error` property remaining null. It also produces no console errors. My code is below:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

function process_file(file) {
    reader.onError = function(evt) {upload_failed("There was an error opening your CSV file. It may be corrupted.")};
    reader.onAbort = function(evt) {upload_failed("There was an error opening your CSV file. It may be corrupted.")};
    reader.onLoad = upload_complete;
    reader.readAsText(file);
    alert('Started');
}
function upload_complete(evt) {
    alert('Complete');
    csv_data = reader.result;
    $submit_button.prop('disabled', false);
}
function upload_failed(message) {
    alert('Failed');
    $submit_button.prop('disabled', true);
    alert(message);
}
```

"Started" is the only alert which shows. The other properties of the reader were accessed through the Firefox console. The process_file function is run through:

```
<input type='file' onchange="process_file(this.files[0])" style="display: none;" accept=".csv"  "id and name etc..."/>
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to have the `onLoad` function trigger when the file is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) docs, the callbacks are passed to `onload`, `onprogress` and `onerror`. You camel-cased them to `onLoad`, `onProgress` and `onError`.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

function process_file(file) {
    reader.onerror = function(evt) {upload_failed("There was an error opening your CSV file. It may be corrupted.")};
    reader.onabort = function(evt) {upload_failed("There was an error opening your CSV file. It may be corrupted.")};
    reader.onload = upload_complete;
    reader.readAsText(file);
    alert('Started');
}
```

Comment: The hours I spent trawling through the web and I missed something so obvious. Thanks! Out of curiosity, why didn't what I was doing generate an error? Was it creating a new variable inside of the FileReader object?

Comment: `FileReader` extends `Object`, so you can set whatever properties you want on it. So setting `onLoad` didn't raise an  error, it just set a property that was never used. 
I made this error many times with the Image and FileReader APIs, it's due to the terrible naming standardization of the various DOM and JS related APIs.